# In a vim split view can we search code in one tab and view the search result in another tab?

Tags: vim-plugin, vim

Suppose we are using split view, while navigating in one view and come across a function definition is there a way to open this definition in another view without switching to the other tab and opening it manually. This will help avoid going back and forth between views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preview window is there for you:

```
:ptag methodname
```

or, with the method name under the cursor:

```
<C-w>}
```

Comment: `<c-w>z` or `:pclose` to close the preview window.